# how to fix the bliking of the balls in the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, blink

An object type of ball is created with a new constructor function ball(color).
Its properties include all that need to paint it on a canvas and to cause him to move in a random direction.
When one ball is created orangeBall = new ball('orange'), it shows up well including its movement on the canvas. But when another one is added, both of them start to blink. 
How to solv it ?
Thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="he">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>
        כדורים קופצים רנדומלית בצבעים שונים
        </title>
        <style>
            html,body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background: black;
            }
            .container { width:900px; margin:0 auto; }
            #canvas { background:#8613eb; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; }
        </style>
        <script>
var ctx;
var H = 800;
var W = 800;

window.onload = function () {

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width=W;
    canvas.height=H;

    function ball(color) {
        //life - the amount of time to show the ball in the screen
        this.life = 60*1000, //1 minute
    this.color = arguments.length==1 ? color: 'white';
    this.x= Math.round(Math.random()*W);
    this.y= Math.round(Math.random()*H);
    this.radius= 10 + Math.round(Math.random()*50);// between 10-60
    this.dx=1+ Math.round(Math.random()*5); //between 1-6
    this.dy= 2+ Math.round(Math.random()*4); //between 2-6
    this.startAngel= 0;
    this.endAngel= 2*Math.PI; //360deg 
    this.speed= 3+Math.round(Math.random()*50) //3-50msec
    this.show = function() {
        //first clear the previous ball 
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var xClear = (this.x-this.radius) <=0 ? 0:(this.x - this.radius);
        var yClear = (this.y-2*this.radius) <=0 ? 0:(this.y - 2*this.radius);
        ctx.clearRect(xClear,yClear,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        //lets stroke the ball
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        this.x+=this.dx;
        this.y+=this.dy;
        if (this.x<0 || this.x>W) {
            this.dx=-this.dx;
            }
        if (this.y<0 || this.y>H) {
            this.dy=-this.dy;
            }
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,this.startAngel,this.endAngel);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        this.life-=this.speed;
        var _this = this;
        //  creating new property in the ball 'timePointer'
        this.timePointer = this.life<=0 ? 
            clearInterval(this.timePointer): 
            setTimeout(function() {
            _this.show();
            },this.speed);      
    }
    this.show();
    };

    orangeBall = new ball('orange');
    blackBall = new ball('black');
//  whiteBall = new ball('white');
//  yellowgeBall = new ball('yellow');
//  pinkBall = new ball('pink');
//  blueBall = new ball('blue');
//  greenBall = new ball('green');

};
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="canvas">Your browser doesn't support this game.</canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have a look at *prototyping* and *inheritance* . Your code will slow down the browser if youve got a lot of balls...

Answer (score 2):

You are clearing your whole canvas after every ball draws itself with its `show` function.  Instead of having the balls clear the canvas, have an interval that will call a function that will clear the canvas once and then iterates all the balls and draw them.

Comment: @Jonasw, true and edited, although if you loop forever it doesn't matter. `draw -> clear -> draw -> clear` vs `clear -> draw -> clear -> draw`.  You'll end up with a blank canvas at the end of the run one way, but it will effectively animate the same.

Comment: but if youre having a timeout inbetween it really matters *clear->await->draw* vs *draw->await->clear* (and not having some kind of timeout willb block the browser...)

Comment: @Jonasw You're right, I had forgotten that.  And if you optimize to only draw when something changes, clearing first is the correct approach.

Comment: clear->draw->clear->draw.. You forget that what is drawn needs to be presented. Its clear -> draw -> display -> clear -> draw -> display. All rendering is done in back buffers content is not displayed untill the function exits. This means you should never use an interval or timeout to render as the content of the canvas is pushed to the display RAM as soon as the function exits. Use `requestAnimationFrame` as that will hold the new pixels in the backbuffer until the display's vertical refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Animations are divided up into frames. A frame is approx 1/60th of a second and in that time all of the animation is drawn.

To help with animations the browser has a function that you use to call the function that renders your frame. `requestAnimationFrame(yourfunction)`

`requestAnimationFrame` will tell the browser that you are making changes to an animation. This stops the canvas being presented to the display until the next vertical display refresh.

Using `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

```
function animateSomething(){
    // draw something    

} // as soon as this exits the content of the canvas is moved to the display
  // there is no way to know where the display hardware is writing pixels to 
  // display, could be halfway through drawing a ball
setInterval(animateSomething,1000 / 60);
```

If you do this for many objects each time you exit the pixels are move to the display without regard to what the display hardware is doing. This causes flicker, shearing and other problems.

Using `requestAnimationFrame`

```
function animateSomething(){
    // draw something 
    requestAnimationFrame(animateSomething)   

} // The content of the canvas does not move to the display until the
  // display hardware is getting ready to scan the next display refresh
requestAnimationFrame(animateSomething);
```

The best way to handle animations is to do all the rendering from one function.

Below i have modified your code to remove the flicker using `requestAnimationFrame` I have added a `mainLoop` function that draws all the balls. I let the browser handle the timing.

```js
var ctx;
var H = 800;
var W = 800;

window.onload = function() {

  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;

  function ball(color) {
    //life - the amount of time to show the ball in the screen
    this.life = 60 * 1000; //1 minute
    this.color = arguments.length == 1 ? color : 'white';
    this.x = Math.round(Math.random() * W);
    this.y = Math.round(Math.random() * H);
    this.radius = 10 + Math.round(Math.random() * 50); // between 10-60
    this.dx = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 5); //between 1-6
    this.dy = 2 + Math.round(Math.random() * 4); //between 2-6
    this.startAngel = 0;
    this.endAngel = 2 * Math.PI; //360deg 
    this.speed = 3 + Math.round(Math.random() * 50) //3-50msec
    this.show = function() {
      //first clear the previous ball 
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
      this.x += this.dx;
      this.y += this.dy;
      if (this.x < 0 || this.x > W) {
        this.dx = -this.dx;
      }
      if (this.y < 0 || this.y > H) {
        this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.startAngel, this.endAngel);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
      this.life -= this.speed;
    }
  };

  orangeBall = new ball('orange');
  blackBall = new ball('black');
  
  whiteBall = new ball('white');
  yellowgeBall = new ball('yellow');
  pinkBall = new ball('pink');
  blueBall = new ball('blue');
  greenBall = new ball('green');
  
  var balls = [orangeBall, blackBall, whiteBall, yellowgeBall, pinkBall, blueBall, greenBall];
  function mainLoop(){
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++){
          if(balls[i].life > 0){
              balls[i].show();
          }
      }
  
  
     requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
  
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#canvas {
  background: #8613eb;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="canvas">Your browser doesn't support this game.</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to use prototype. Is that better ?
In addition it's not smooth enough. 
Added also performance timeline for your help.

```js
var ctx;
var H = window.innerHeight;
var W = window.innerWidth;

window.onload = function () {

 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 canvas.width=W;
 canvas.height=H;

 function ball(color) {
  //life - the amount of time to show the ball in the screen
  this.life = 60*10, //duration of 600 X 16ms(fram per sec)
  this.color = arguments.length==1 ? color: 'white';
  this.x= Math.round(Math.random()*W);
  this.y= Math.round(Math.random()*H);
  this.radius= 10 + Math.round(Math.random()*50);// between 10-60
  this.dx=1+ Math.round(Math.random()*5); //between 1-6
  this.dy= 2+ Math.round(Math.random()*4); //between 2-6
  this.startAngel= 0;
  this.endAngel= 2*Math.PI; //360deg 
  this.start = null;
 };
 ball.prototype.show = function() {
   //lets stroke the ball
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
   this.x+=this.dx;
   this.y+=this.dy;
   if (this.x<0 || this.x>W) {
    this.dx=-this.dx;
    }
   if (this.y<0 || this.y>H) {
    this.dy=-this.dy;
    }
   ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,this.startAngel,this.endAngel);
   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.fill();
   this.life--;
  };
 var arrBalls = [] ;
 arrBalls.push(new ball('orange'));
 arrBalls.push(new ball('black'));
 arrBalls.push(new ball('white'));
 arrBalls.push(new ball('pink'));
 arrBalls.push(new ball('blue'));
 arrBalls.push(new ball('green'));
 
 // This loop shell be less then 10ms inorder not to maintain
 // 60fps interval of screen hardware rendering
 var balldeth = 0;
 function paint() {
   //clear the canvas once in xframes
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   //paint balls in the canvas
   for (var i = 0; i < arrBalls.length; i++ ) { 
    arrBalls[i].life >= 0 ? arrBalls[i].show() : ++balldeth;
   } 
  (balldeth == arrBalls.length) ? console.log("game over"):window.requestAnimationFrame(paint);
 }
 
 window.requestAnimationFrame(paint);
 
};
```

```css
   html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
   }
   #canvas { background:#8613eb; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; }
```

```html
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas">Your browser doesn't support this game.</canvas>
 </body>
```

[image]

Comment: Balls have some kind of vibrations.